# Banned Dependencies in Jboss Wildfly

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly, guice

I'm working on migrating a legacy application from Jboss 6 to Wildfly 18. When I try to package up my application via maven I get the error:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1
Found Banned Dependency: javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1
Found Banned Dependency: stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1
Found Banned Dependency: org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25
Found Banned Dependency: com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.6
Found Banned Dependency: com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.2.3
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  7.775 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-10-22T12:50:47-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (ban-bad-dependencies) on project Common: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
```

Upon looking into this, my project does indeed have some dependencies on artifacts that are listed as 'Banned' by the maven-enforcer plugin in the wildfly pom. Some of the dependencies I have been able to work around, but there are others like Guice that would be very difficult to remove. I know I could override the enforcer settings in my own poms, but I don't want to do that without some idea of why they were blacklisted in the first place.

Dose anyone know where I can find documentation explaining why certain artifacts are blocked by wildfly? Has anyone tried using Guice with wildfly successfully?

**Update:**

the parent for my pom:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
   <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
   <version>18.0.1.Final</version>   
</parent>
```

Comment: I don't have any idea, and what's flabbergasting is that, according to the source code history, this ban is present since the very first commit.

Comment: what wildfly pom are you using?

Comment: @ Tomaz Cerar                                <parent>
     <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
     <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
     <version>18.0.1.Final</version>
  </parent>